# How do I search for files containing a range of numerics using windows DIR command?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, dir

I want to be able to isolate and search using the windows DIR command for only the files that contain an extra numeric at the end.  How do I do this?  I  have attached a picture that shows an example of one of my directories the link is below at the end.

"Track 01 1.m4a" and some are named "Track 01.m4a"?  How can I list just the ones that were added with the numeric at the end?  Also while we are at it?  I have multiple duplicates sometimes 4 or five so I'm expecting to have to search for files with a range of numbers like "* [1-4].m4a"

If I can be clearer in my question please ask.

List of files:

[image]

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

Comment: Use the findstr command in Windows.  Pipe the output of a recursive dir command to findstr and use the proper command line switches to find the files you are looking for using regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir /b | findstr
```

will let you do what you want to do.

Comment: Thx ymar, my understanding is dir is sending its output to findstr where I can use better searching commands.  Correct?

Comment: What if next I want to delete those files I just searched for?

Comment: @DanielMiladinovich You can do something like 

dir /b | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] [0-9].m4a"

This will display all the files that have the pattern digit-space-digit.m4a in them. Unfortunately, to delete these files, you might have to use a FOR loop.